# 'datasets.ImageFolder' doesnot working in python

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, torchvision

when I run this piece of code I get this error:
NameError: name 'datasets' is not defined

how can I solve this?
Many Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from torchvision import transforms
from torchvision.datasets.folder import default_loader
np.random.seed(random_seed)
torch.manual_seed(random_seed)


train_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder("/content/gdrive/My Drive/val2017", 
transform)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using anaconda distribution, first install torchvision using:

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge torchvision
```

and then

```
from torchvision import datasets
```